# Why does the sun not burn your retinas when in peripheral vision?

Tags: optics, lenses, sun, vision, biology

After going to the ophthalmologist and having bright lights shone in my eyes, I was thinking about how the brightness only hurts when I looked at the light. When it was in my peripheral vision, it didn't.

This got me thinking, and I feel like I've observed a similar thing with the sun. Looking directly at the sun obviously hurts, yet looking up at the sky with the sun in my peripheral doesn't hurt (or at least much less). I haven't been blinded by sunlight yet either, despite at times spending *hours* outside with the sun in my peripheral vision. Compare this to actually looking at the sun, which can take mere *seconds* before permanent retinal damage.

**Why is having the sun in peripherals so much less damaging? What physics are involved that reduce the intensity so much?**

Comment: It seems to be biology, the "macula" at the center of the retina can be more easily damaged ttps://www.zeiss.com/vision-care/int/better-vision/understanding-vision/the-complexities-of-the-human-eye-from-the-blind-spot-and-macul.html

Comment: @annav I don't see in that link how the macula can be more easily damaged, just that it has the highest density of photoreceptor cells

Comment: different cells in peripheral, rods, https://www.medicinenet.com/peripheral_vision/definition.htm ."Peripheral vision is the work of the rods, nerve cells located largely outside the macula (the center) of the retina. The rods are also responsible for night vision and low-light vision but are insensitive to color."